# Typescript error: "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never' " when trying to check keys of a type

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I have a custom type that represents a row on a webpage table and I am trying to implement the ability to edit the row. The following is my code where I try to get access to each field of the Media type.`

```
  const handleEditFormChange = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const fieldName: string = event.currentTarget.name;
    const fieldValue: string = event.currentTarget.value;

    const newFormData: Media = editFormData as Media;

    newFormData[fieldName as keyof Media] =  fieldValue;

    setEditFormData(newFormData);
  }
```

`

The error i am getting on the "newFormData[fieldName as keyof Media]" is

"Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'"

All help is appreciated! This is the Media type:

```
export type Media = {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    artist: string;
    rating: string;
    category: string;
    release_date: string;
    genre: string;
}
```

Previously had `

```
newFormData[fieldName]
```

but it was giving "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Media'"
`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use *generics* here, enforcing that the second parameter can only be a key of `Media` and the third parameter is enforced actually to be the same type as typeof `Media[T]`.

```
const handleEditFormChange = <T extends keyof Media>(event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const fieldName = event.currentTarget.name as T;
  const fieldValue = event.currentTarget.value as Media[T];

  const newFormData = {} as Media;

  newFormData[fieldName as T] = fieldValue;
};
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&ts=4.8.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCywAmBLAhnAXjgG8AoOObTALjgDsBXAWwCNgoBuchbGAG2C0AzjCjY6Acy4VcsbCOGjxU7lFwxlisZOlwAxuuAToiLct1RgA3EOAB9TIbM7uE4HUvOVAXy6k9EHQicAAWuHSYAgCiODAAYtBMAMJhkqhEADwAKnCgMO6YQnAA1sCIEABm6Fh4AHwAFMAAbu4wtOGIAJSEtSTcza0AdGCWLXQwACLAFbgMfDD1nboBQfAV2FaYAHK4TOm5YzCDegxQluNZsm5HdLuoNnBZy4HB65sAarh8DPsD48enc4wS5Qa6DJpfH5wB4YHC4ADaWQAun4KCtgnRgAB3BJQJgTdT4IjEbzQoqwvCo%20jY3H4wnwt58bZ3MmPJGEOCMzCfb7ALi%20UhAA)